# D3 interpolated line curve is janky and doubling back on itself

Tags: d3.js, svg, interpolation, linechart, curve

I'm not sure quite how to describe this. The picture basically explains it:[image: cardinal]

The faded dots are the points on the curve. You can see the line doubles back on itself and overlaps. I'm just setting it to :

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date_spaced);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.score);
    })
    .interpolate('cardinal');
```

And each point is only getting plotted once. What am I doing wrong?

And with monotone:

[image: monotone]

And linear:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem...I'm hoping for a hint to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Try to increase the tension:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date_spaced);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.score);
    })
    .interpolate('cardinal').tension(0.95);
```

Also, try other interpolations (and tension values, but just for "bundle" and "cardinal"), until you find something that fits your purposes.

Comment: I tried to increase the tension but that just minimised the problem, it didn't get rid of it. If I want to get rid of the problem, I need to remove interpolation completely and just have a straight line.

Comment: Did you try "bundle" with high tension? Also, did you try other interpolations (monotone, basis...)?

Comment: Bundle and Basis are no good because I need the line to intersect the points. Monotone has the same problem (I've added the image to my OP)

Comment: Did you set the tension to 1 (that's the maximum)? Also: do you have only 5 data points in your data? Is xScale a time scale?

Comment: When tension is 1 then it's just straight lines, no curves. I have 7 points (I put the full graph on the OP) and yes xScale is is a time scale

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the cardinal curve interpolation, the line was coming back loopy everytime. Setting it to [MonotoneX](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveMonotoneX) instead gave me exactly what I wanted to see.

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    // ...
    .interpolate('cardinal');
```

[image: cardinal]

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    // ...
    .interpolate('monotoneX');
```

[image: monotoneX]

You can read all about the different kinds of interpolations in d3 [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529). (Careful, lots of math theory involved...)